# Integrating Color Switcher plugin in to Magento - Zoom & Lightbox are not showing switched image

Tags: javascript, php, magento

On Magento, I am integrating a [color switcher plugin](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/color-switcher-free.html) and it works when you choose a colour from the dropdown menu, however the zoom and lightbox elements don't display the switched image, instead it shows the default product image.

Here is the code in Media.phtml:

```
<p class="product-image">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->backgroundColor(array(255,255,255))->resize(638,900); ?>"  rel="<?php echo implode($config, ',');?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()) ;            
    echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');?>" id="zoom1" class="cloud-zoom">   

    <?php
    echo '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->backgroundColor(array(255,255,255))->resize(425,600).'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'"/>';            
    echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
    ?></a>

<?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
 <a id="zoom-btn" class="lightbox-group zoom-btn-small" href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->backgroundColor(array(255,255,255))->resize(638,900); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getImageLabel(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Zoom'); ?></a>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var assocIMG =  // Added  - Removed { here, causes issues with other scripts when not working with a configurable product.
    <?php 
    if ($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable") {
        echo "{";
        $associated_products = $_product->loadByAttribute('sku', $_product->getSku())->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts();
        foreach ($associated_products as $assoc)
            $dados[] = $assoc->getId().":'".($assoc->image == "no_selection" || $assoc->image == "" ? $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $_product->image)->resize(375,460) : $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($assoc, 'image', $assoc->image)->resize(375,460))."'";
    } else {
        $dados[] =  "''";
    }
    echo implode(',', $dados );     
    if ($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable") {
        echo "}";
    }
    ?> ;
//]]    
</script>
```

I tried to integrate the image ID within the Zoom and Lightbox code, but I failed to get it to work, here is what I tried:

```
<?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 0): ?>
 <a id="zoom-btn" class="lightbox-group zoom-btn-small" href="<?php echo **'<img id="image" src="'.** $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->backgroundColor(array(255,255,255))->resize(638,900); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getImageLabel(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Zoom'); ?></a>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Here is the page I am working on: http://www.moramoraswimwear.com/magento/index.php/swimwear/view-all/test-4

What do I need to do in order to get the correct image to be linked? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: when you are changing the image src form IMG tag then you have to also change that same image in A tag which is just above the IMG tag.
A tag have Zoom1 id..

Comment: I tried changing to ID in the A tag to id="image" but it didn't work, do you know what I am doing wrong? Thanks for your help!